# What is this shape $r=a+b\cos(n\theta)$ called?

Tags: terminology, polar-coordinates, curves

The polar equation $r=a+b\cos(\theta)$ produces a limaçon and for different ratios of $a$ and $b$, more precisely $|\frac{a}{b}|$ it produces inner looper limaçons, cardiods, dimpled limaçons and convex limaçons.

So, now if we decide to stretch the the curve a little more $r=a+b\cos(n\theta)$, then we end up with so many graphs.

Is there a name for the general shape? for different values of $a$ and $b$ what are those called?

Comment: I know the term "rose" applies to things of the form: $r=b\cos(n\theta)$, but things get weird once you add in the $a$ term. It might still be used in the more general case, but I'm not certain.

Comment: the equation in some cases does produce a rose. but, not always.

Comment: Right, I know that they don't all look like roses, but I was suggesting that perhaps they are all called roses regardless.

Comment: well, let's wait for the answer. I hope somebody knows.

Comment: As I suggested: https://brilliant.org/wiki/polar-curves/#types-of-polar-curves

Comment: Thank you so much, I forgot to check the brilliant wikis also, probably will hit two birds in one stone. :D

Comment: There is no point varying both $a$ and $b$, only their ratio matters.

Answer (score 4):

They are called *cyclic-harmonic curves*. They are not roses but *conchoids* of roses.

https://www.mathcurve.com/courbes2d.gb/conchoidderosace/conchoidderosace.shtml

Depending on the ratio $a/b$, they are said *curtate*, *cuspitate* or *prolate*.

https://www.jstor.org/stable/1967850?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents

Comment: Thank you so much, I was also very confused when brilliant wrote it as roses(as some of them weren't). Cyclic-harmonic is the word